# change the url on the input of the searchbox

Tags: php, html

I have this form - How can I make the input on the text input go on the url?

```html
<form class='divtabellinacenter' name='primo_form' action='elencoget.php".$url."' method=post>
  Filtra per<br> Cognome <input class='emailtext' type=text id='filtrocognome' name=cognome value='Cogn' oninput=''>
  <input type='hidden' id='savecognome' name='savecognome' value=''> 
  Nome <input class='emailtext' type='text' name='nome' id='filtronome' value='Nom' oninput=''>
  <input type='hidden' id='savenome' name='savenome' value=''>
</form>
```

Comment: You mean you want a querystring? If so change `method=post` to `method=get`

Comment: fyi, neither `$_POST['cogn']`, `$_GET['cogn']`, `$_POST['nom']` or `$_GET['nom']` are available anywhere from your form. (unless they are set somewhere we don't see)

Comment: I removed irrelevant PHP code